# Getting dependencies of a shared library that could be located at any folder

Tags: linux, makefile, dependencies

I'm creating a `Rules.make` file, similar to Linux's 2.0 version, which contains all kinds of targets - including `.so` files. My goal is to then only need to make minimalistic Makefiles like so:

```
include $(DIR_TOP)/Rules.make
```

in the directories that contain any source files I need compiled. The rules also enable me to create targets like so in the "main" Makefile:

```
something: something_else lib.so
```

, so that `something_else` is done first, and then `lib.so` is built.

Everything has been going smoothly, until I decided to add dependencies to the aforementioned shared library target. I figured something like the following would do the trick:

```
${DIR_OUT}/%.so: $(shell find $(dir $@) -name *.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(CLIBS) -shared $^
```

However, to my demise, `$(dir $@)` apparently expands to `$(dir ${DIR_OUT}/%.so)`, which then results in simply `${DIR_OUT}`, which is exactly not what I need. `DIR_OUT` is simply the top-level directory string, but the target may be invoked from any sub-directories, or simply like `target: $(DIR_OUT)/path/to/lib.so`. I was hoping that `%` could match not only file names, but also any directories (which it does), and then have that expanded to `$@` once it's already decided what the full path is. Doesn't work like that. With this solution, not only the object files I need are included in the building process, but also any other object files that are there in the output folder, and that then produces errors of kind `multiple definition of x y z` etc.

Is there any other way to get the list of dependencies for the shared library I want to build? Ideally a purely Makefile based solution, but if there isn't one, I'm fond of some `bash` scripting too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be **[secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html)**:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
${DIR_OUT}/%.so: $$(shell find $$(dir $$@) -name *.o)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(CLIBS) -shared $^
```